# Find Office group for a sharepoint site

Tags: powershell, office365

One of our users deleted an office group that resulted in locking the site as well.
I could unlock the site, but I would like to recover the associated group too.
the site url like /sites/abc
I found an office group, but that belongs to a different site like /sites/abc2

I would like to restore the office group that belongs to a given site (checked the SharePointSiteUrl property), because it will be really deleted after 30 days.
I made a small script to iterate trough groups, but didn't find any group belonging to this site, probably, because it is still deleted state.

```
$groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited
Foreach ($g in $groups) 
{
    if ($g.SharePointSiteUrl -eq "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/abc") {
    Write-Host $g.Name
    }
}
```

How can I find which group I need to restore based on the url only?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can expose it with the `-IncludeSoftDeletedGroups` switch of [`Get-UnifiedGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps)

> The IncludeSoftDeletedGroups switch specifies whether to include soft-deleted Office 365 groups in the results. You don't need to specify a value with this switch.
>
> This switch is required to return soft-deleted Office 365 groups.
>
> Soft-deleted Office 365 groups are deleted groups that are still recoverable.

However the association to the site might not exist anymore either. Check the properties of the returned objects and perhaps filter the ones that were only deleted / deleted recently.

Comment: If this does not help I can just delete it.